# Implementing Bull Queue in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, queue, message-queue, job-scheduling

I try to implement Bull queue in Typescript and NestJS,
my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MailService {
    constructor(
        @InjectQueue('mail')
        private readonly mailQueue: Queue
    ) {}

    async addToQueue(): Promise<void> {
        this.mailQueue.add(() => {
            return this.sendMail(); 
        })
    }
    
    
    async sendMail(): Promise<void> {

        //logic to implement

        this.addToQueue();
    }
}
```

fast question: Is this implementation sufficient for my job queuing to work?,
If not: what i must to do?

Comment: do you create an mail.processor?

Comment: yes//////////////

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently wrote a blog post that seems to relate to your use-case:

https://firxworx.com/blog/coding/nodejs/email-module-for-nestjs-with-bull-queue-and-the-nest-mailer/

A few tips:

- In your module, be sure to import your `BullModule` (from `@nestjs/bull`). For example, you need to configure with your queue name ("mail" in your case) and setup your queue. A common setup would include configuring with the redis hostname and port.
- In your service, you need to add *jobs* to the queue, along with optional *payload*. In your case, you are trying to add a function. Instead, you should add a job name, e.g. "confirmationEmail", and pass a payload, e.g.`user` and `token`. My example would look like this: `await this.mailQueue.add('confirmationEmail', { user, token })`
- You need to implement a *processor* for your queue. This is a class decorated with the `@Processor(QUEUE_NAME)` decorator from `@nestjs/bull` (`@Processor('mail')` in your case). The processor handles jobs that are added to the queue.
- In your processor, you could implement a method e.g. `sendConfirmationEmail()` that handles the job named "confirmationEmail". You would decorate that method with `@Process(JOB_NAME)`, e.g. `@Process('confirmationEmail')`. The method can receive your payload. Per my example, the following method signature would provide the `user` and `token`: `async sendConfirmationEmail(job: Job<{ user: User, token: string }>): Promise<any>` (note `Job` is from the `bull` package, and that you may wish to type your return vs. using `any`). Here is where you would actually send out the email.
- In your processor class, `@nestjs/bull` also provides special method decorators including `@OnQueueActive()`, `@OnQueueCompleted()`, `@OnQueueFailed()`. Refer to the docs but you may find these useful for logging or other purposes.

The idea is that your processor handles jobs in the queue when the app is otherwise idle.

Your mail module would presumably have at least a `mail.module.ts` with configuration, a `mail.service.ts` that adds jobs to the "mail" queue, and a `mail.processor.ts` that takes care of completing any jobs added to the "mail" queue.

Further documentation from NestJS is available at:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues

Comment: Great! Thanks man!, one additional question, how can i handle logic in e.q. @OnQueueActive instead of logging?

Comment: Hey I'm glad it helped. The method decorated with `@OnQueueActive()` will be passed the job as a param (e.g. method signature: `onQueueActive(job: Job)`). Therefore inside the method you have access to `job.id`, `job.name`, `job.data` and can go from there. I don't think you necessarily need to put logic in there though, as you could write a `@Process()` decorated method in most cases to break up your code a bit better.

Comment: To round out my comment, `@OnQueueCompleted()` decorated methods receive the `job` and `result` as params, and `@OnQueueFailed()` decorated methods receive the `job` and `error` as params.

Comment: i have one last question, can you show an example of tests of the this bull queue in Jest?

Comment: Great and thorough article there.

Comment: @Qumber does the IoC work with workers? i'm trying to resolve a dependency but it fail although the service is in the same module with the processor class.

Comment: Article link appears to be dead unfortunately :(

Comment: @chris-owens thanks for the heads up. the web host changed from cpanel to directadmin and it looks like htaccess got messed up. #$@#!

I will add to my pile to fix. In the meantime notice the URL redirected to https://firxworx.com/blog/code/email-module-for-nestjs-with-bull-queue-and-the-nest-mailer.html/ (note the .html/ that got appended) if you manually fix to replace trailing ".html/" with "/" in your address bar the link will work for you.

Comment: @chris-owens and I fixed the busted .htaccess situation, the URL from the post will work as-is now. thanks for the heads up, much appreciated.

Comment: Legend, thanks for that!