# Can't resolve dependency when try to inject a Bull Queue in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, bull-queue

I'm trying to implement Nodemailer with Bull/Redis to handle email-type of tasks in NestJS.

I have a shared module called `EmailService` that add a job to my queue, to do this, it needs to inject the `Queue` from `'bull'`.

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmailService (?). Please make
> sure that the argument BullQueue_mailqueue at index [0] is available
> in the SharedModule context.

My structure

```
├── src
|  ├── app.module.ts
|  ├── config
|  |  └── nodemailer
|  |     ├── nodemailer.module.ts
|  |     ├── nodemailer.service.ts
|  └── modules
|     ├── modules that imports the SharedModule to send emails.
|  └── shared
|     ├── processors
|     |  └── email.processor.ts
|     ├── services
|     |  └── email
|     ├── shared.module.ts
```

app.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    NodemailerModule,
    // Al other modules (functionalities of my application that imports the SharedModule)
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

nodemailer.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: NodemailerService,
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      useClass: NodemailerService,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [NodemailerService, BullModule], // <- Exports BullModule
  providers: [NodemailerService],
})
export class NodemailerModule {}
```

NodemailerService

```
@Injectable()
export class NodemailerService implements BullOptionsFactory {
  constructor() {}

  createBullOptions(): Promise<BullModuleOptions> | BullModuleOptions {
    return {
      name: 'myqueue',
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
      },
    };
  }

}
```

Now this is my EmailService that is part of SharedModule.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Queue } from 'bull';

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('myqueue')
    private readonly mailQueue: Queue,
  ) {}

}
```

SharedModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [NodemailerModule], // < imports this because it has the Bull configuration as we saw above
  exports: [EmailService],
  providers: [EmailService, EmailProcessor],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

I have tried to follow the steps on:

1. https://firxworx.com/blog/coding/nodejs/email-module-for-nestjs-with-bull-queue-and-the-nest-mailer/
2. [Implementing Bull Queue in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894243/implementing-bull-queue-in-typescript)

I cannot see why my `EmailService` cannot inject the BullQueue dependency.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 15):

The module that injects the queue needs to import the queue registration. I.e.

`folder/some.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'some-queue',
    }),
  ],
  providers: [SomeService],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Then in `SomeService`

`folder/some.service.ts`

```js
constructor(
  @InjectQueue('some-queue') private someQueue: Queue,
) {}
```

Comment: Greate! I was trying to register the queue in another module, and import it in my module, but it doesn't work. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import bullModule in app module.
as documentation:
In order to prevent the creation of `BullConfigService` inside `BullModule` and use a provider imported from a different module, you can use the `useExisting` syntax.

```
BullModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useExisting: ConfigService,
});
```

so import BullModule for root is neccessary

view documentation: [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues)

Comment: Still getting the issue. I'm not sure this is mandatory because I can declare de bull configuration in any other module, and just import that module in the app.module, just like I did. Take a loot at my `nodemailer.module`, it has the bull module configuration.

Comment: @RRGT19 that is mandatary. please read documentation and example in the end of page as i updated answer

Comment: I tried it but still getting the issue. I know that `BullModule.forRoot` is necessary, what I mean is that I can put that in other module and imported it in the app.module. Putting that out side for now, with your suggestion I received another error: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BULL_CONFIG(default)`. I really don't know what is the issue or what is wrong.